# $event.stopPropogation is not a function error in Angularjs Unit Test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to unit test a function that is bound to the ngClick directive. It looks something like this for now as we've just started on this project and before I get to far I want some test coverage:

```
vm.open = function($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
            vm.opened = true;   
        };
```

I unit test like this:

```
describe('Unit: simpleSearchController', function(){
//include main module
beforeEach(module('myApp'));
var ctrl, scope, event ;
// inject the $controller and $rootScope services
// in the beforeEach block
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
    // Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    // Create the controller and alias access using controllerAs
    ctrl = $controller('simpleSearchController as vm', {
        $scope: scope
    });
}));
// unit tests
it('should set vm.opened to true', function(){
    event = scope.$broadcast("click");
    expect(event).toBeDefined();
    scope.vm.open(event);
    expect(event.defaultPrevented).toBeTruthy();
    expect(scope.vm.opened).toBeTruthy();
});
});
```

When Karma runs the test I get this error:

```
TypeError: $event.stopPropagation is not a function.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `$($event).stopPropagation();`?

Comment: When you broadcast an event there is no stopping propagation right? broadcast goes down, stopPropagation is for emit. Did you try using $emit. or just create a mock event object and just spy on the methods. You do not really need to test `expect(event.defaultPrevented).toBeTruthy();` it is already tested as a part of angular core.

Comment: you are correct @PSL, please add as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your issue is that there is no `stopPropagation` method on the **[`$broadcasted`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1209)** event. broadcast propagates down and stopPropagation (available in **[`$emit`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#LC1137)**) is used to prevent further propagation upwards. So you have 2 options.

Either use `$emit`

```
  it('should set vm.opened to true', function(){
        event = scope.$emit("click");
        expect(event).toBeDefined();
        scope.vm.open(event);
        expect(event.defaultPrevented).toBeTruthy();
        expect(scope.vm.opened).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Or just create a mock object for event.

```
  it('should set vm.opened to true', function(){
            event = jasmine.createSpyObj('event', ['preventDefault', 'stopPropagation']);
            scope.vm.open(event);
            expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(scope.vm.opened).toBeTruthy();
      });
```

Also note that you really do not need to test `expect(event.defaultPrevented).toBeTruthy();` or `expect(event).toBeDefined();` because this is core angular functionality when preventDefault is called and it has already been tested.

Comment: How o do this in angular 6. please guide

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of using stopPropagation() you can use return false. stopPropagation is a jQuery method so it should be used on jQuery objects.

This should get the same desired effect:

```
vm.open = function($event) {            
        vm.opened = true;   
        return false
    };
```

Comment: I do not think so this is angular and it does not look for return value. It will suppress the error from OP though. OP is doing it in the wrong way.

Comment: @JohnStewart Test will pass. :) But this is not jquery event. This is custom event created by angular. Your test itself is incorrect.

Comment: You are correct, just looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false